# In linux terminal how to open a ssh session and type bash command inside the ssh session using gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, gnome-terminal

**Problem:**
I tried Using the Below commands but no use, it only ssh to the machine but not execute the command "bash" after connected to ssh target.

**Trails:**

```
Method #1 : gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e "/bin/bash -c 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1;bash;bash'"
Method #2 :  gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e "/bin/bash -c 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1;bash'"
Method #3 : gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e "/bin/bash -c 'ssh 10.10.10.1 ;bash'"
Method #4 : gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1;bash'
Method #5 : gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1"bash;bash"'

this method#4 #5 closes my open terminal
```

**Note:** "a fake IP (10.10.10.1) is entered for posting example only so pls dont get misleaded"

Help is highly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: Most of these works for me, though all you really need is `gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e 'ssh 10.10.10.1'` (Provided you have bash or at least some shell set as the login shell on 10.10.10.1. Does everything work if you just run `ssh 10.10.10.1` from your current terminal ?

Comment: @nos thank for reply.. simple ssh 10.10.10.1 works fine, but  my requirement is login ssh and type bash on the remote ssh terminal. so the command  gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e 'ssh 10.10.10.1' login to 10.10.10.1. but i want after that to execute automatically "bash" command there...

Comment: You would need  `-e 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1 /bin/bash'` then, or whichever full path you have to bash on 10.10.101  (Note there's no semicolons, but you need the -t in this case). But the setup of your 10.10.10.1  machine is rather odd if yo need to explicitly run bash, so I suspect there's something else that could trip you up.

Comment: @nos your command "gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e 'ssh 10.10.10.1 /bin/bash'" open a terminal blank and hangs there, Thanks

Comment: Yes, I edited it, you need the -t argument

Comment: @nos shall we able to execute anymore command after bash into it in the same gnome command? like below ? gnome-terminal --tab -t "NASIR-QEMU" -e 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1 /bin/bash pwd ls'

Comment: No, not like that. You'd have to write it like `-e 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1 /bin/bash -c "pwd ; ls"'` , but it's unclear what your goal is at this point, you might be better off creating a shell script on your 10.10.10.1 machine that you run instead, especially if you do not need an interactive terminal

Comment: @nos thanks , i tried the above one as you mentioned ( gnome-terminal --tab -t "RDESKTOP" -e 'ssh -t 10.10.10.1 /bin/bash -c "pwd;ls" '
)and it closes the window. My requirement is open multiple ssh and type diff command in each ssh session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138685/discussion-between-ragav-and-nos).

Comment: `bash` cannot run in non-interactive and interactive at the same time. What you have tried actually ran except it is not what you needed. If you do need to run multiple commands, run `bash` last if you intend it to be interactive. Try `-e 'ssh 10.10.10.1 "ls; pwd; bash -i"'`.

Answer (score 1):

use `ssh 10.10.10.1 /bin/bash` as you need to specify the absolute path.
try doing echo to test if this works since you will at least be able to see some output as the ssh login also logs into a terminal- the very same command that you are executing.. i.e. bash. so you may not be able to distinguish